# Generating python wheels for different architecture with wheel 0.35.x

Tags: python, setuptools, python-3.8, python-wheel

I am trying to generate a wheel package on x86_64 build machine for aarch64 target. However starting from python 3.8 I get following error message:

```
AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp38', 'cp38', 'linux_aarch64')
```

By investigation, I found, the error is raised in "packaging" python package, which is used by wheel 0.35.1, used by setuptools, for generating supported tags on particular interpreter. The packaging module has replaced the pep425tags.py (starting from 0.35.0 release). The problem is the packaging module reports as supported tags only tags for the native architecture of the build machine, in my case 'x86_64'.

How to use use the setuptools (and wheel 0.35.0+) in Python 3.8 for generation wheels for various architectures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Guido would approve, but I just commented out the offending assert in `bdist_wheel.py`.  I don't know why this cross-compilation is not allowed, so do test nothing blows up.  For me it's so far so